# Phaser 3 scene input.on() touch events not trigerred

Tags: phaser-framework

I have the following setup inside the constructor of an angular component (ionic project).

```
   let config = {
      type: Phaser.AUTO,
      width: '100vw',      
      height: '100vh',
      transparent:true,
      disableContextMenu: true,
      parent: 'phaser-example',
      physics: {
          default: 'arcade',
          arcade: {
              gravity: { y: 200 }
          }
      },
      scene: {
        preload: function() {
          that.preload(this);
        },
        create: function() {
          that.create(this);
        },
        update: function() {
          that.update(this);
        }
      }
    };

    this.game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

and I set a listener for a click/touch event in the create method as follows:

```
create(scene){
   scene.input.on('pointerup', this.moveSourceSprite, scene);      
}
```

However, the moveSourceSprite is never called. When I listen for pointerupoutside and click on the game, the moveSourceSprite is called however.

I suppose, the scene does not listen the whole game area for some reason.

I am brand new to Phaser and stuck at this point. I'd be grateful if you could help me out.

Thanks,

Doug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var myScene1 = {
    key:'scene1',
    preload: function(){
      this.load.image('alien1', 'sprites/phaser-alien.png');;
    },
    create: function(){
      this.add.image(100, 100, 'alien1');
      this.input.on('pointerup', ()=>{game.scene.start('scene2'); game.scene.stop('scene1')}, myScene1);
    },
}

var myScene2 = {
    key:'scene2',
    preload: function(){
      this.load.image('alien2', 'sprites/alien2.png');;
    },
    create: function(){
      this.add.image(100, 100, 'alien2');
      this.input.on('pointerup', ()=>{game.scene.start('scene1'); game.scene.stop('scene2')}, myScene2);
    },
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 600,
    height: 600,
    loader: {
    baseURL: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nazimboudeffa/assets/master/',
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    },
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    scene: [myScene1, myScene2]
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
game.scene.start('scene1');
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.19.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, I do appreciate it. Your example is in line with the documentation. However, my clicks can only be captured as outside events for some reason. I mean instead of pointerup, pointerupoutside works, which leads me to think that there is a problem with the hit area. However, I could not figure it out yet.

Comment: Try to post some code in jsfiddle and share it a comment i'll take a look at it

Comment: Hi Nazim, huge thanks for your time. Your JS code works just fine. I think my problem is to do with the html connection. I use ionic so it might be to do with that, as well. Basically, the <div> that I target as phaser parent, almost puts phaser to the background! Therefore, it cannot capture the click. For instance, when I put a background color to the div, I cannot see the phaser scene. Is this normal? I played with the z-index but that did not help. Have you seen anything like this before?

Comment: The above comment is misleading as I noticed game objects can capture the click. It is just related to the scene for some reason...

Comment: Lot of questions Doug I don't know by which one I start so to begin with we just work with canvas it means you give it an id or you let phaser automatically add it to the HTML5 page, please try a jsfiddle or codepen it's better to talk about the code ;)

Comment: Hi Nazim, I would have added the code but that requires a whole ionic project. Otherwise, I cannot replicate it. I think it is due to a conflict with the ionic touch listeners. Hence, closing this and accepting your answer as it is the proper way to call phaser touch events. Thanks again for your time, I do appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome Doug, but you know there is another way of sharing code, is to pass by a GitHub repo ;) I wonder to see how you coded your project as am usually using cordova and have seen som ionic attemps but not so much :)